# Live video streaming through proxy

Tags: java, tcp, proxy, udp, video-streaming

I have two endpoints behind firewalls who can only communicate through an external relay/proxy.

I'm going to stream video frames from one endpoint to the relay to the other endpoint. It doesn't matter if frames are lost - the main requirement is that latency is as low as possible. Frame order is also fairly important.

Which would be best suited to this, UDP or TCP? What additional considerations would I need to make if I used UDP? Are there any other better suited protocols/libraries I could use? I'm doing this from Java.

Comment: I don't think RTP is in IP broadcast. RTP stream uses IP multicast service (usually UDP multicast) and it usually splits into two different multicast groups: one for video chunks and one for audio chunks. But, usually the user will see both as one session name. This session is handled by RTCP control port which can be in IP unicast or IP multicast. Considering this, RTP is a combination of IP unicast and IP multicast. If RTCP control port is forced to IP multicast, everything is now in IP multicast; we still need to manage 2 multicast groups (video & audio). The proxy needs to look into this.

Comment: Check on heading **2.3 Mixers and Translators** on how to deal with firewall in [RFC1889 - RTP: A Transport Protocol for Real-Time Applications](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1889.txt). Translator can be something to translate IP multicast into IP unicast at firewall point.

Comment: Topic on [IP multicast](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726985.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you description (frame order is not significant, some frames can be dropped) - UDP (or protocol based on UDP) is an ideal candidate. Here's [some](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_media#Protocol_issues) information about various protocols that can be used to stream live video